# Android Dialog Handler in external class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Good evening. I'm a beginner in Android development. I don't want to dirty my main activity class, that why i want to use some external class (is it all right that i give "this" for some external classes?). My problem maybe rather simple. I want to show AlertDialog.
So my class

```
public class Dialogs {

public static void exitActivity(Context c ){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(c);

    //Construct dialog
    builder.setMessage("Are your sure you want to exit?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);

    //Listener for yes button
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            FifteenActivity.c.finish(); ////<<< Here is an error >>>>//
        }
    });

    //Listener for no button
    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}

}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.newGame:
        restart();
        return true;
    case R.id.settings:

        return true;
    case R.id.info:
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        return true;
    case R.id.exit:
        Dialogs.exitActivity(this);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And is it a "good practice" to create all menu in external class?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about passing "this", that is a typical way to pass the Context between classes.  It is best not to hold onto the Context and just use it within the scope of the call (just like you have done in this small example for exitActivity).  The onOptionsItemSelected( ) typically I will keep as part of the Activity and use a class/static call for your Dialog class like you have set up.  That segregates the code a bit and makes things more readable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and how i can finish activity from external class? See <<<<Here is an error>>>> in my code

Comment: It's useful if you can provide error messages from the LogCat printouts of your program when the crash occurs.  That will typically get the best response so we know if it is a NullPointerException or it can't cast to class, or something of that nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you would like to finish an Activity using a separate class by passing along the context and then calling finish upon it.  The way described above should suffice.

```
public static void exitActivity(Context activityContext){
   ...
   (Activity)activityContext.finish();
   ...
}
```

Yes, as mentioned in the other post, you should be sure you are passing the correct context.  The context could relative to a view or a thread, etc.  So be sure that you pass in the Activity context.

Comment: Thanks, it works. So we must to cast our context to Activity. `code` ((Activity) activityContext).finish(); `code`

Comment: The base class 'Activity' has the finish functionality.  Casting it to a specific class of your own that extends the 'Activity' class would also work of course.  '(MyActivity)activityContext.finish();' or using the class itself 'myActivityClass.finish();'

Answer (score 0):

Its not a bad idea to separate your dialog code in a third class. Specially when you are showing same dialog throughout the application.

while passing context make sure that you pass activity context and not application context.

And you will be able to use the same context to finish your activity.